# RedisJson rejson.so file not created

Tags: redis, redisjson

i am trying to setup Redisjson on redis-server

*git clone https://github.com/RedisLabsModules/rejson.git*

*cd rejson/*

*make*

after the make command i dont have a file called *rejson.so* anywhere however *make* command finished without error

so that's why i cant load module to my redis

i am using ubuntu 20.04
i also have tried to clone from https://github.com/RedisJSON/RedisJSON.git and it didn't work either

Comment: Can you please share the error?

Answer (score 1):

Cloning **master** from each of those repositories produces a *librejson.so* in the target/release directories. Cloning the **1.0** branch produces *rejson.so* and the docs in each branch point to the appropriate shared object.

Can you share your output?

Comment: i load module with librejson.so its working thanks

Comment: @AliMertcanTekin Can you stamp as solved?